# Find dependencies for Dynamics CRM entity's attribute

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm struggling to find dependencies for CRM entity attribute from C# code, but I cannot find the right way.

The code like this:

```
var attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = "invoice",
    LogicalName = "billto_city"
};

var attributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)proxy.Execute(attributeRequest);

var dependenciesRequest = new RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest
{
    ObjectId = (Guid)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata.MetadataId,
    ComponentType = (int)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata.AttributeType
};

var dependenciesResponse = (RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse)proxy.Execute(dependenciesRequest);
```

Gives negative result. I suppose it's incorrect to use attribute `MetadataId` as `ObjectId`. But it seems it is impossible to find out `ObjectId` for attribute.

Does anybody faced with similar task before? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use *AttributeMetadata.AttributeType* property, which indicates the type of attribute (string, lookup, picklist, boolean etc.) but you need the *componenttype* value, which is type of solution component (Entity, Attribute, Relationship, Option Set etc.). In your case its 2. The full table of component types and their codes may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546.aspx#bkmk_componenttype).